# TableAdapter fill query with variable

Tags: vb.net

I have two related tables. 1 table contains books and the other table contains the libraries that own the books. Now I only want to see 1 library with the books. There is a variable called IDGemeente. It is defined as integer. Now I want to fill the Tableadapter with the data using a FillBy query
The query is defined like this:

```
SELECT        BoekGemeenteID, GemeenteID, BoekID, IsUitgeleend, KerenUitgeleend, LaatstUitgeleend, Aanschafdatum, KastPlank, Kenmerk
FROM            BoekenGemeenten
WHERE        ('GemeenteID' = '%IDGemeente%')
```

But the result is nothing. How can I use a variable in the query?

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLCnS.png)

Comment: What does this have to do with LINQ? How is what you showed related to VB.Net?

Comment: Firstly, you don't "fill the Tableadapter". The table adapter doesn't contain any data. It's the `DataTable` that gets filled and it gets filled by the table adapter.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-parameterized-tableadapter-queries?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause doesn't make any sense. It is comparing two different strings for equality so of course no records could possibly match it. Depending on your database, your `WHERE` clause should probably look like this:

```sql
WHERE        (GemeenteID = @GemeenteID)
```

or maybe this:

```sql
WHERE        (GemeenteID = ?)
```

You should then name your method `FillByGemeenteID` and, when you call it, pass your `IDGemeente` variable as an argument.

Comment: I have tried that before. My query is:
SELECT        BoekGemeenteID, GemeenteID, BoekID, IsUitgeleend, KerenUitgeleend, LaatstUitgeleend, Aanschafdatum, KastPlank, Kenmerk
FROM            BoekenGemeenten
WHERE        (GemeenteID = @GemeenteID)
I call the query like this:
Me.BoekenGemeentenTableAdapter.FillByGemeenteID(Me.BoekenBewVerwDataSet.BoekenGemeenten, New System.Nullable(Of Integer)(CType(GemeenteIDToolStripTextBox.Text, Integer)))

The output is nothing. What is wrong with the query?

Comment: When I execute the query and give as variable '1' then the result is nothing.
When I give the variable IDGemeente then I get an error:
The conversion from string IDGemeente to type integer is invalid